# depth of field with webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl

I would like to simulate the "depth of field"-effect in webgl, 
moving the camera on a circle: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Depth_of_Field

In OpenGl I would use the accumulation-buffer. But unfortunately webgl doesn´t know such buffer.

Is it possible to use blending to simulate such an effect?

Answer (score 4):

A simple way of simulating depth of field is

- Render scene to texture
- Blur texture with renderer scene to another texture
- Mix the 2 textures (in focus scene texture + blurred scene texture) using the depth information.

There's [an example here](http://webglsamples.org/field/field.html). Click the tiny * to and adjust the "dof" slider. Press `d` a few times to see the different textures.

Comment: thats simply great!

Answer (score 1):

You can also render the scene to several different framebuffers, then bind those framebuffers as textures and accumulate the color from all of them in one final post-processing gathering pass. So that is more or less the manual way of doing accumulation.

Comment: OK, now I can create framebuffers and I can render to textures. :) But I don´t think, that this is a good idea, to create so many framebuffers. You would need a lot of memory space.

Comment: It probably isn't a very good idea. However AAA games can use up to 12 framebuffers. Alternatively, you can do it with two, by ping-ponging between the two somehow, or rendering and then blitting, or some similar combination of the two buffers only.

Comment: I think, i have found an other version. 

I use 2 different shaders: The first vertex-/fragment-shader renders a szene as normal. The second vertex-/fragment-shader is responsible for combining 2 textures to 1 texture.

Comment: STEP 1: render szene with first shader and write result into framebuffer 0.

Comment: STEP 2: render szene with first shader and write result into framebuffer 1. Then combine texture of framebuffer 0 with texture of tramebuffer 1 with the second shader. Write the result into framebuffer 2.

Comment: STEP 3: render szene with first shader and write result again into framebuffer 1. Then swap framebuffer 0 with framebuffer 2. Combine textures of these framebuffers with the second shader.

Comment: LAST STEP: render szene with first shader and write result again into framebuffer 1. Then swap again framebuffer 0 with framebuffer 2. Combine textures again with the second shader. Write colors into canvas.

Comment: As you have mentioned, this would be with ping-ponging. Do you think, that my idea is ok?

Comment: Yeah, one normal fbo and one accumulated fbo and corresponding shader sounds okay. There you go then.